# Using caching with a strongly typed service implementation in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, servicestack

I have my service definitions, which use strongly typed return DTOs via the IReturn interface

```
[Route ("/items/{id}", "GET")]
public class FindItems : IReturn<FindItemResponse>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class FindItemResponse { ... }
```

I also use that type with my service's implementation

```
public FindItemResponse Get (FindItems request)
{ 
   ... 
}
```

This worked very well, until I tried to use ServiceStack's caching abilities. According to [the documentation](http://docs.servicestack.net/caching), one should use the `Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache? method, which returns object and not FindItemResponse. I checked the actual return type, sometimes its a JSON string, sometimes its a`ServiceStack.CompressedResult`, so no chance to manually convert it.

How is caching supposed to be done in ServiceStack, when you use a strongly typed response (as is recommended by @mythz)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToOptimizedResultUsingCache` returns a `CompressedResult` on subsequent calls because it's returning the **cached compressed bytes** of the format (e.g. json) being requested.

This should be a transparent implementation detail for your clients which just receive a cached version of your Service. When using `ToOptimizedResult*` APIs your Service needs to be able to return a Cached response so you'll need to change the return type to `object`, e.g:

```
public object Get(FindItems request)
{ 
    return Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache,cacheKey,()=> 
    {
        return new FindItemResponse { ... }
    });        
}
```

Changing from an `object` to `ResponseDto` return Type is functionally equivalent and has no behavioral differences.

Since it has no effect my Services almost always have an `object` return Type unless I need to call it internally from other Services using `base.ResolveService<T>`, it's more important to specify the Response Type in the `IReturn<T>` interface marker, e.g:

```
public class FindItems : IReturn<FindItemResponse> {}
```

Which will enable the succinct typed APIs that .NET clients will be able to take advantage of.

An alternative to using `ToOptimizedResult*` APIs is to use the newer [[CacheResponse] Attribute](http://docs.servicestack.net/cacheresponse-attribute) which will let your Services return a Typed Response DTO, e.g:

```
[CacheResponse(Duration = 60)]
public FindItemResponse Get(FindItems request)
{ 
    return new FindItemResponse { ... }
}
```

Where for subsequent calls will return the cached response instead of calling your Service.

Comment: The CacheResponseAttribute works fully automatic? No need for cache keys or anything else? My problem with changeing the response type to `object`, is that it would break my unit tests, which all call the service.Get methods directly.

Comment: @mat yeah it uses the `RawUrl` as the Cache Key by default. The [Advanced CacheInfo Customization](http://docs.servicestack.net/cacheresponse-attribute#advanced-cacheinfo-customization) shows an example of how you can use a custom key.

Comment: The ChacheResponseAttribute is independent of the session, I assume. I'm asking, because I might have to throw an error, depending on which user tries to access the route, and that check should not be circumvented by the cache.

Comment: @mat You can use the `VaryByUser=true` attribute modifier if you want caches to limited on a per-user basis.

Comment: And it even works with my unit tests. Your product never ceases to amaze me, @mythz, thanks a lot. One last question: Can I somehow check (on the server or client side) if a response came from cache or was freshly calculated?

Comment: @mat No cached responses are indistinguishable to clients (other than their improved performance :). You'll need to add something like a `DateTime.UtcNow` property in your Response DTO so you can tell when the DTO was cached.